# Взлом wifi и прослушка трафика

Tags: безопасность, wifi, роутер, lan

Ситуация:

1. Дома стоит роутер, раздает wifi + к роутеру по проводу подключен ноутбук, wifi сеть запаролена;
2. Злоумышленник получает доступ к wifi сети, и получает доступ к админке роутера;
3. Злоумышленник уже может не напрягаясь прослушивать весь трафик проходящий по  беспроводному соединению wifi.

Вопросы:

1. Может ли злоумышленник прослушивать и трафик ноутбука, который подключен проводным соединением?
2. Как обезопасить проводное и беспроводное соединение в такой ситуации?

Comment: У провайдера стоит обязательный по закону «чёрный ящик» с оборудованием [СОРМ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%9C), позволяющим слушать трафик любого абонента этого провайдера. Кто и как имеет реальный доступ к этому оборудованию, и как (хорошо?) оно реально защищено вопрос открытый. Может, знакомый, работающий у подрядчика, занимающегося этим оборудованием, даст технический пароль по дружбе?

Прослушка трафика может быть где угодно между вашим ноутбуком и другим «концом». Смотрите на вопрос шире.

Comment: Пароль смени и перезагрузи роутер

Comment: Читал о способе взлома wifi, где сетевой адаптер переключали в режим мониторинга, далее найдя клиента wifi сети, отправляли ему пакет от имени роутера с просьбой переподключиться, далее устройство переподключалось к wifi и пакет с паролем  брагополучно улетал злоумышленнику. Если так просто получить пароль, имеет ли смысл повышать сложность пароля?

Comment: На практике пароль зашифрован, многое зависит от сложности шифрования. WEP взламывается за пару секунд, WPA/WPA2 -- за пару лет.

Comment: И, если быть точным, то отправлялся пакет с сообщением о разрыве соединения (disconnect-атака).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на первый вопрос: да, может. Для этого и доступа к админке роутера не надо. Злоумышленник может прослушивать wi-fi трафик и так, без взлома (не особо напрягаясь).

Ответ на второй вопрос: если не хотите, чтобы сидели через ваш роутер -- смените пароль. Если "пусть сидят" -- используйте шифрование, где только можно (https вместо http в вебе, если сайт поддерживает).

Comment: Я полагал, что прослушка может происходить только по категориям подключения устройств, т.е. если взломали беспроводное соединение, то можно слушать только беспроводной трафик, если же подключились к проводному, то только проводной, поправьте меня если я неправ.

Comment: Роутер рассылает пакеты всем, принимают только те, кому они предназначались (и те, кому они интересны).

Comment: Остается только подключаться напрямую, минуя роутер и надеяться что по пути, никто не подсоединился к проводам))?

Comment: Однако, в большинстве случаев _внешний_ роутер т. е. отдельный, подлючен к основному, фильтрует пакеты не для устройств. Самый простой способ проверки -- nmap 192.168.0.1/24 (иногда 192.168.1.1/24) на wi-fi устройстве.

Comment: Спасибо @val ! Не ради спора - все же, остается непонятным, как можно прослушивая wifi трафик, получить доступ к трафику который был передан роутеру по Ethernet, может подскажете где об этом доходчиво написано? Пакеты Ethernet, как я понимаю, в воздухе не появятся?

Comment: Ну, честно говоря, не уверен. Однако, можно послать ARP-запрос. После этого, все устройства будут слать трафик через это устройство (а оно - на роутер)

Comment: да поэкспериментировал, трафик всех подключенных к роутеру устройства по Ethernet кабелю так же видны через wifi канал.